# jUnit not found in androidTest folder but found in test folder

Tags: android, junit4, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I am writing instrumented tests in android but when I import `jUnit` (to use `@RunWith` annotation), it is not able to find jUnit but I am already using jUnit in unit tests (under `test` folder). I am not able to even start writing the tests.
Same thing is happening with `AndroidJUnit4` class.

I have included this stuff in `build.gradle` :

```
testCompile brazilGradle.testbuild('junit')

androidTestCompile brazilGradle.testbuild('AndroidSupportTestPackage-rules')
androidTestCompile brazilGradle.testbuild('AndroidSupportTestPackage-runner')
```

I have also included this in defaultConfig :

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

How come it is working in one folder and not in another ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The silly error on my part was that by Build Variant was set to `debug` and by changing it to `release` I was able to use dependencies not available to me earlier.
If anyone cannot find this setting, this can be seen as a `Build Varaint` tab at the bottom left corner. Clicking on that should open a small panel containing the app module and the corresponding build variant. Clicking on that column should show the dropdown with `release` and `debug` and any other flavors if any.

Comment: funny thing is that I changed it from release to debug and now the dependencies are ok.